# What does CommentsOnFilesDisabled tenant property do?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, governance

There is a tenant property `CommentsOnFilesDisabled` that has no documentation describing what it does exactly. Does anyone know any additional information?

[image: nli]

After changing this property at a tenant, I can still add comments for documents. So I am really confused as to what this property is really doing.
[image]

Any insight is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in this article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps

*-CommentsOnFilesDisabled*

*Disables or enables commenting functionality on the files. PARAMVALUE: $true | $false*

Maybe you need to wait some time (24h?) for it to take real effect.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what this settig actually does? I have created this question after carefully reading anything I could find and it still makes no sense to me.